# What is the role required to add an IAM policy binding to a Google Pub/Sub topic?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam

I'm trying to follow these instructions, https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/dead-letter-topics#assigning_the_publisher_role, to grant Pub/Sub permission to publish messages to a dead-letter queue, but I'm encountering a `PERMISSION_DENIED` error:

```
gcloud pubsub topics add-iam-policy-binding my-dead-letter-topic --member="serviceAccount:$PUBSUB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT" --role="roles/pubsub.publisher"
ERROR: (gcloud.pubsub.topics.add-iam-policy-binding) PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action.
```

Helpfully, the Google Cloud console shows that I need the `pubsub.topics.setIamPolicy` permission:

[image]

My question is: how would I go about acquiring that permission? Would I have to be a project IAM admin (cf. [You need permissions for this action. Required permission(s): resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59770167/you-need-permissions-for-this-action-required-permissions-resourcemanager-pr))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, exactly. You'll need to be assigned one of the roles that contains the `resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy` permission. As you pointed out, the answer to [You need permissions for this action. Required permission(s): resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59770167/you-need-permissions-for-this-action-required-permissions-resourcemanager-pr) outlines the different role options.

Project IAM Admin is recommended because it's the most specific role you can be granted to be able to set the IAM policy.

Comment: I noticed later that Pub/Sub Access Control is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#roles. The Pub/Sub Admin (`roles/pubsub.admin`) role is sufficient to obtain the `pubsub.topics.setIamPolicy` and `pubsub.subscriptions.setIamPolicy` permissions needed to set up forwarding to dead-letter topics.